# Rails form_for selectbox with defined values view value from db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have such form partial for CRUD actions:

```
= form_for @vehicle do |f|
    = f.select :fuel_type, [["Выбрать", "None"], "Бензин", "Дизель", "Газ", "Гибрид", "Электричество", "Другое"], {:required => true, :selected => @vehicle.fuel_type}
```

So as you can see in db i store hole word, as for example Бензин or Дизель etc...

But when i try to edit using my form partial some data, i see that as default selected value of my selectbox is None (displayed as Выбрать). But when in db that field is Бензин why it is set to None in form view? How to see Бензин?

Also note that for new action @vehicle.fuel_type will be empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pair the labels with a value, and store the value in the database as an integer:

```
 [['Бензин', 1], ['Дизель', 2], ['Газ', 3]]
```

You can include blank on your collection to select none:

```
f.select :fuel_type, [['Бензин', 1], ['Дизель', 2], ['Газ', 3], ...], { :include_blank => "Выбрать" }
```

In this way you won't need `:selected => @vehicle.fuel_type` on your edit form as the value will be populated from the model if selected.

There is probably a better way to handle it and this functionality could also be done in the model, but to display the saved value you could create a helper method:

```
  def map_fuel_type(value)
    case value
      when 1
        'Бензин'
      when 2
        'Дизель'
      when 3
        'Газ'
      when 4
        'Гибрид'
      when 5
        'Электричество'
      when 6
        'Другое'
    end
  end
```

And then to show the value on your index or show page:

```
<%= map_fuel_type @vehicle.fuel_type %>
```

To store as string:

```
f.select :fuel_type, ["Бензин", "Дизель", "Газ", "Гибрид", "Электричество", "Другое"], { :include_blank => "Выбрать" }
```

Comment: but when so, than i need in index, show actions to change view, so that compare 1,2,3etc with values

Comment: Hi Valdis, I'm not sure I understand. What is your question?

Comment: if i will store in db integer values, not string how than to view this?

Comment: Rails knows to map the appropriate text based on the integer value. Test out my example, it should work for you.

Comment: in selectbox yes, but how to be if in show view i must output it just like text, not selectbox

Comment: good idea, i set +1, but also will accept if you write how to do with string's in db, not with in values in select

Comment: It doesn't seem wise to use a string as your identifiers in dropdown. But I have updated to handle this. Please mark as answer.

Comment: also maybe you know how using html to put such logic: user must select one value from selectbox, so that "Выбрать" could be not send to method, only normal values?

Comment: so what do you thiink